# Encoding with pandas.read_csv when file name has accents

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, encoding, pandas

I'm trying to load a CSV with pandas, but am running into a problem if the file name has accents. It's clearly an encoding problem, but although `read_csv` lets you set encoding for text within the file, I can't figure out how to encode the file name properly.

```
input_file = r'C:\...\Datasets\%s\Provinces\Points\%s.csv' % (country, province)
self.locs = pandas.read_csv(input_file,sep=',',skipinitialspace=True)
```

The CSV file is Anzoátegui.csv. When I'm getting errors,

```
input_file = 'C:\\...\Datasets\Venezuela\Provinces\Points\Anzoátegui.csv
```

Error code:

```
OSError: File b'C:\\PF2\\QGIS Valmiera\\Datasets\\Venezuela\\Provinces\\Points\\Anzo\xc3\xa1tegui.csv' does not exist
```

So maybe it's converting my string to bytes? I tried using `io.StringIO(input_file)` as well, which puts the correct file name as a column header on an empty `DataFrame`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [C:\PF2\QGIS Valmiera\Datasets\Venezuela\Provinces\Points\Anzoátegui.csv]
Index: []
```

Any ideas on how to get this file to load? Unfortunately I can't just strip out accents, as I have to interface with software that requires the proper name, and I have a ton of files to format (not just the one).  Thanks!

Edit: Full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PF2\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 891, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\PF2\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\pydevd_vars.py", line 486, in evaluateExpression
    result = eval(compiled, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 404, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 205, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 486, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 594, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 952, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "parser.pyx", line 330, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:3040)
  File "parser.pyx", line 557, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:5387)
OSError: File b'C:\\PF2\\QGIS Valmiera\\Datasets\\Venezuela\\Provinces\\Points\\Anzo\xc3\xa1tegui.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: Can you compare the file name in `os.listdir` ?

Comment: The file names show up correctly in os.listdir: os.listdir(path='C:\...\Datasets\Venezuela\Provinces\Points')
['Amazonas.csv', 'Anzoátegui.csv', 'Apure.csv', 'Aragua.csv', 'Barinas.csv', 'Bolívar.csv', 'Carabobo.csv', 'Cojedes.csv', 'Delta Amacuro.csv', 'Distrito Capital.csv', 'Falcón.csv', 'Guárico.csv', 'Lara.csv', 'Miranda.csv', 'Monagas.csv', 'Mérida.csv', 'Nueva Esparta.csv', 'Portuguesa.csv', 'Sucre.csv', 'Trujillo.csv', 'Táchira.csv', 'Vargas.csv', 'Yaracuy.csv', 'Zulia.csv']

Comment: hmmm, and does `pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.listdir()[1]))` work?

Comment: No, that does not work, and produces the same OSError as above: `OSError: File b'C:\\PF2\\QGIS Valmiera\\Datasets\\Venezuela\\Provinces\\Points\\Anzo\xc3\xa1tegui.csv' does not exist`

Comment: I think the file name is being treated with the default Python encoding UTF-8 within read_csv, which can't handle accents. Trying to convert to latin-1.

Comment: Fishy! I think this could be a bug, do you mind posting this as an issue on github?

Comment: Interestingly I have no idea how to do that - I'm pretty new to the open-source world. Do you mean on the [pandas Issues page](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)?

Comment: that's precisely what I mean :) Also, please include the entire stacktrace (both here and on github). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added the rest of the error, and I'll try posting on github as well.

Comment: I had no issues with read_csv on python 2.x with any file names (containing accents, cyrillyc symbols and other unicode chars), so I believe this is a python 3.x bug. Added relevant tag.

Comment: It may be an issue with an old version of pandas (0.13.0 vs. 0.14.0). Working to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok folks, I got a little lost in dependency hell, but it turns out that this issue was fixed in pandas 0.14.0.  Install the updated version to get files named with accents to import correctly.

[Comments at github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7345).

Thanks for the input!