# Pandas not able to open file with umlauts in path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Try to read the content from file `hello.txt` at path `C:/temp/Kälte/Grad°/`:

> Message; Content
>
> Greeting; Hello World!

```
path = 'C:/temp/Kälte/Grad°/hello.txt'

# OKAY
data = ""
with open(path) as f:
    data = f.read()
print("file content:\n" + data)

# OKAY
import csv
with open(path, 'r') as csvfile:
    print("reading csv file:\n"+path)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
     
# FAILURE
import pandas as pd
print("reading csv file with pandas:\n"+path)
dataframe = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';',names=["Message","Content"],header=1)
print (dataframe)
```

I remember the exact same problem from several years ago, and I wonder why nobody resolves such a basic issue in pandas. Doesn't pandas call python's `open` internally (because then it should work, shouldn't it)? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a recurrence of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140297/pandas-read-csv-cant-import-file-with-accent-mark-in-path), but the solutions there didn't help on my set-up.

Here's a manual solution if there's no other option:

```
path = r'C:/temp/Kälte/Grad°/hello.txt'

import pandas as pd
import csv

with open(path, 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';')
    cols = next(reader)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(reader), columns=cols)

print(df)

    Message        Content
0  Greeting   Hello World!
```

Comment: Had this issue (umlaut in filename) with pandas 0.23.4 with python 3.7 (anaconda) under Win10 64bit and this worked for me! Thanks!