# Pandas read_csv filepath with special characters codec can't decode

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, filepath

I am using Python version 3.5.3 and Pandas version 0.20.1

I use read_csv to read in csv files. I use a file pointer according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140297/pandas-read-csv-cant-import-file-with-accent-mark-in-path) (I prefer this over the solution using `_enablelegacywindowsfsencoding()`). The following code works:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("C:/Desktop/folder/myfile.csv") as fp:
    df=pd.read_csv(fp, sep=";", encoding ="latin")
```

This does work. However, when there is a special character like ä in the filename as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("C:/Desktop/folderÄ/myfile.csv") as fp:
    df=pd.read_csv(fp, sep=";", encoding ="latin")
```

Python displays an error message: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte oxc4 in position 0: unexpected end of data.

I also tried to add a 'r' before the filepath, however I get the same error message, except that now I get a position as integer number which is exactly where my special character is in the filepath.

So the reason is the special character in the filepath name.

(Not a decode error which can be solved by using encoding="utf-8" or any other like ISO-5589-1. To be absolutely sure, I tried it with the following encodings and always got the same error message: utf-8, ISO-5589-1, cp1252)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates your *source file* (not the data file) is not encoded in UTF-8.  In Python 3, your source file must either be saved in UTF-8 encoding, or you must declare the encoding that the source file is saved in with a special comment, e.g. `#coding=Windows-1252` at the top of the file.  `\xc4` is the Windows-1252 encoding of `Ä` and is the default encoding for Western European and US Windows, so it's a good guess.  Ideally, re-save your source in UTF-8.

For example, if the source is Windows-1252-encoded and the data file is GB2312-encoded (Chinese):

```
#coding=Windows-1252                         # encoding of source file
import pandas as pd
with open('DÄTÄ.csv',encoding='gb2312') as f:  # encoding of data file
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Note that source files default to UTF-8 encoding, but `open` defaults to the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(FALSE)`.  Since that varies with OS and configuration, it is best to always specify the encoding when opening files.

Comment: The file was exported as UTF-8. I opened the file and re-saved it with the text editor as UTF-8. As I said, when I try it with the filepath without "Ä" it does work. I tried it again with a "Ä" in the file path name. I get the same error message. I tried your code (except I did not use gb2312, I tried it with utf-8, utf8-sig and latin. Furthermore first I used your f and datafile, second I tried it with my fp). So I test it with exactly the same file. First test is that I use a file path name without a "Ä" in it and it works. Then I try it with an "Ä" in the filepath name and error message.

Answer (score -1):

Try using unicode file paths `u'path/to/files'` for example

```
import pandas as pd

with open(u'C:/Desktop/folderÄ/myfile.csv') as fp:
    df=pd.read_csv(fp, sep=";", encoding ="latin")
```

Comment: The OP is using Python 3.  The strings are already Unicode.